# UIpagecontrol Need Animation Rigth to Left

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Using UIControlpage in my application. load the image and display in page control successfully. but i want to display the images animation like right to left move. Using timer call page control and increase the array count.

//// using NSTimer to call function to show the animation.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(loadNextController)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

ScrollViewPage = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, frameX, frameY)];
ScrollViewPage.pagingEnabled = YES;
ScrollViewPage.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
ScrollViewPage.delegate = self;
ScrollViewPage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
ScrollViewPage.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frameX, frameY);
ScrollViewPage.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;


ScrollViewPage.pagingEnabled = YES;
pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(100,self.view.frame.size.height-100,self.view.frame.size.width-200,100);
pageControl.numberOfPages = [_pageImages count];
pageControl.currentPage = 0;

[self.view addSubview: ScrollViewPage];

for(int i = 0; i < [_pageImages count]; i++)
    {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[_pageImages objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        _backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tmpImage];
         _backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(frameX * i, 0.0, frameX, frameY);
        [ScrollViewPage addSubview:_backgroundImageView];


    }

ScrollViewPage.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frameX*[_pageImages count], frameY);
pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
[pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pageTurn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

///// Here call the timer function

```
- (void)loadNextController
{
     pageControl.currentPage = (pageControl.currentPage+1)%self.pageImages.count;
     ScrollViewPage.contentOffset = CGPointMake(pageControl.currentPage * self.view.bounds.size.width, 0);
}
```

Here i need to show left to right move in uipagecontrol. help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should always write what is your current result, what is the expected result and what have you tried.

I can only guess the issue you are facing is there are no animations.
The scroll view has a method `setContentOffset:animated` which you can use to animate the transition. Another approach is to use `UIView` `animateWithDuration` and sett the offset in the method block.

Try any or both of these...

```
[ScrollViewPage setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageControl.currentPage * self.view.bounds.size.width, 0) animated:YES];
```

Or

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        ScrollViewPage.contentOffset = CGPointMake(pageControl.currentPage * self.view.bounds.size.width, 0);
}];
```

**EDIT:** Loop images.

To loop images you really only need 2 images on the scroll view at the time. I will show you the concept with 3 and you can try and play around with it.

```
NSArray *allImages;
NSInteger currentIndex = 0;
UIScrollView *scrollView;
UIImageView *imageViews[3];

- (void)begin {

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*3.0, scrollView.frame.size.height); // always have 3 images at the time
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, 0.0); // put to center

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*i, 0.0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        imageView[i] = imageView;
    }
    [self layoutForIndex:currentIndex];
}
- (void)nextImage {
    currentIndex++;
    [self layoutForIndex:currentIndex];

    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, 0.0) animated:YES]
}

- (void)layoutForIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if(allImages.count > 0) { // we need at least one image to do something
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            // do the circling
            NSInteger imageIndex = index-1+i;
            while(imageIndex < 0) imageIndex+=allImages.count;
            while(imageIndex >= allImages.count) imageIndex-=allImages.count;

            imageViews[i].image = imageViews[imageIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

But in general for what you are doing you do not even need a scroll view. On next you can simply add another image view next to the current one and then use the `UIView` animation to reposition both of the image views.

Comment: One doubt.. after display all the  images in [_pageImages array ] and how move the first images in uipagecontrol without animation. that means all the images are come back and go to first image. i need it automatically come to first image. help me...

Comment: I added the concept for this. I hope you will understand it.

Comment: Im using scrollViewDidScroll to change the images.. so after show the all images it automatically move to first image.